# TypeLoadExceptionHolder cannot be converted to type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, casting

I have create a RepairsCategoryField object the same as I have for many objects, marked it as [Serializable]. Then added it as a field on a configuration object. Which is serialized and deserialized when the application saves and starts respectively.

But I am getting this error I have never seen before. Had a look online and can’t seem to find any information.

Object of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.TypeLoadExceptionHolder' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Deeplake.Cmgr.Configuration.RepairsCategoryField]'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, my dumb mistake really.

I was trying to use field names that had already been used in the past with diffrent values.

Changed it up and now it is working fine.

The error message was most unhelpful though.